# Blue light filter for Windows - what does it actually do?

Tags: windows

Technically what does it actually do and why is reducing the blue channel on your screen different to using a dedicated program (as a number of people in the office are telling me).

Comment: Different in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference - both are equally useless.

I quote from Wikipedia
[Effects of blue light technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_blue_light_technology):

> Current academic and medical consensus suggests there are no known health effects of day-to-day exposure to blue light (visible light with wavelengths 400-450 nm), and it is not regarded as a cause of eye disease, eye strain, or disruptions to circadian rhythm, as distinct from any other frequency band of visible light. Despite the lack of scientific basis, numerous products and software claim to filter out blue light to prevent eye strain and sleep disruptions. It is illegal in the UK for a health practitioner to indicate to a patient that 400-450 nm blue light causes health effects or affects sleep. Harvard appears to have retracted their health claims regarding blue light in 2018.

There are some claims that blue-light from screens in your bedroom may cause
sleeplessness, but I for one am sure that any lighted screen in my bedroom may
be problematic for sleep, blue light or not.

Comment: Interesting perspective. I do wonder if Wikipedia overreaches though? My research (and tests on my environment and experience) link blue/white light (to reduced melatonine I brlieve) and greatly ease waking up. Likewise I replaced a white LED with a red one on my stupid fancy bedside clock and it made a world if difference at night.

Comment: @davidgo: I have read other articles that said the same, Wikipedia was just the easiest to find and quote. I'm not a specialist on the human eye, so can only guess that red is less noticeable than white at night.

Comment: Personnally speaking I play games on my laptop in bed until 12:00pm every night  with no filter and I suffer no problems with sleep. The question arose from be suggesting that a user "might as well reduce the blue and green channels on the display"